# is there a way to make an infinite while loop run in the background?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop

When the user clicks the button, i want a function to keep happening infinitely UNTIL the user presses that button again.
I have tried creating a function similar to the one below but i get stuck into an infinite loop and program can't take in the second user click so it can turn off the function and reset the changes made.

```
function doThing(){
    setBtnValue = "OFF"
    if( setBtnValue !== "ON"){
        setBtnValue = "ON"
        while (setBtnValue="ON"){
            //do this indefinitely
        }
    }
        //perform this on second button click
    if (setBtnValue !== "OFF"){
        setBtnValue = "OFF"
        // call function that will reset changes made to the element
    }
}
```

Comment: while(setBtnValue == "ON")

Comment: What is "this" that you want to do indefinitely? There's almost certainly a better way.

Comment: "i want a function to keep happening infinitely UNTIL the user presses that button again. " this is bad approach in a "single threaded" environment like a browser. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @VishalDhawan i won't be able to access setBtnValue on the second if statement

Comment: You see, i have a grid that contains squares within it. i have a function that can paint the squares random colours when called, now i want that function to run infinitely when a button is pressed and then stop when said button is pressed again!

Here's my fiddle (it has an error on line 126 as it can't access button value on second if statement: https://jsfiddle.net/gkoyuptc/4/

Comment: You'll have to store the state you set somewhere else (globally) so that it can be passed in the function and checked. Also as others suggested, there should be some better way to do this other than running a while loop continuously in the background

Comment: Well, you need to give the browser time to render your changes to the square colours, so your "tight" loop would freeze it up anyway. Consider using `requestAnimationFrame`, testing to see if the squares should be changing, and only change them then.

Comment: Also consider to use a simple setInterval to be the “loop”. It’s not the most sophisticated manner, although it should remain easy to see the concept of a basic timer to perform updates: setInterval(callback, 100). eg. where the “callback” advances the board state. Use frame skipping (ie. it’s okay to run multiple *logic* state advances, even though some intermediate display states are omitted) each time the timer is called to a ensure more-or-less consistent timing..

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thank you for the requestAnimationFrame! it works like a charm but i'm having a hard time bringing down the number of FPS and be able to stop the thing. Appreciate the help!

Comment: To “stop”, simply _don’t make changes_: if (running) { do_stuff(); }. To control the FPS (or rather, the state change speed), use a time delta (change magnitude of calculations, including iterations based on variable timing) or frame skipping (hold a constant FPS and run fixed-step updates, possibly multiple in a single pass), which should be covered in game tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your function/code to check if there is a button click inside of the while loop. You should also use the setTimeout() method to delay the loop briefly, so you don't have 100's of loops in less than a second, as that can cause browsers to freeze and for a debugger to crash.